# Why is my popular ☺ smileyface ☺ question not listed among my top questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, top-questions

On my [top questions list](https://stackexchange.com/users/262054), my [very top question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451524/why-arent-and-valid-javascript-variable-names) isn't showing up. What's going on here?

Comment: It's not Community Wiki, the account IDs match... the only thing that comes to mind that the `◎ܫ◎ and ☺` characters break something internally, causing the question to vanish.

Comment: :O Stack Overflow is trying to destroy happiness by ignoring questions that have a smileyface ☺ in their title!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our service responsible for aggregating posts across the network failed to record that the question was [re-opened](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7451524/revisions) almost immediately after being closed. As we look into exactly what happened, I've manually corrected this entry in the database, so your question is correctly appearing in your [top questions](https://stackexchange.com/users/262054?tab=top) now.

Comment: Wow, I never even noticed that it was ever closed.

Comment: By the way, I remember the same question never made it to the hot questions list even though it definitely qualified for it. Do you think this is related?

Comment: Yup, definitely related. Sorry to deny you your moment of glory :(

Comment: Have you figured out/fixed the underlying problem?

Comment: Yes, we've figured out the problem. This bug has a low chance of occurring whenever a question is closed and then *immediately* re-opened. We haven't fixed it just yet though ..it's on the todo.txt.